# rails_admin: Can I add a field to a model's CSV export without explicitly listing all fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rails-admin

I'm using `rails_admin` and have a model whose parent's parent is relevant and should be included in lists and exports (i.e. `asset.owner.manager` is aliased as `asset.manager`). I can include this field like so:

```
config.model 'Asset'
  list do
    field :manager
    # BUT then I have to include all the other fields explicitly here
  end
  export do
    field :manager
    # AND here...
  end
end
```

Is there a way I can avoid:

1. repeating all the field names, and
2. repeating the process for `list`, `export`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is answered by `include_all_fields` to include the defaults.

The second problem can be solved with a `Proc` object, though this is not ideal. (I'd like if there were a `all_actions` method or something like that.)

Here's the code I've ended up with:

```
config.model 'Asset' do
  fields = proc do
    field :manager
    include_all_fields
  end
  list &fields
  export &fields
end
```